# Javascript: Executing code when a close tab event occurs in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a few lines of code that i need to execute when a particular tab is closed in Chrome. The **onbeforeunload** returns a String and wouldn't work otherwise. Is there any way I can do this?

PS- This is for a Chrome Extension. I am writing the code in content.js file.

Comment: Please refer to this hope it can help you http://superuser.com/questions/704779/how-to-enable-confirmation-alert-before-closing-chrome-tabs

Comment: Good description of how to subscribe for tab events here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19972322/getting-the-page-events-tab-closed-lost-focus

Comment: @WasiqMuhammad that is not what i want to achieve. I have some calculations that should occur only when the tab is closed. Suppose i want to know the time(in ms) when the tab was closed. I can use **new Date().getTime()**. but its not working inside **onbeforeunload**.

Comment: @AndriyIvaneyko chrome.tabs.* is accessible in background.js. I want to do this from my content.js itself. I need a way in javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code below should fix your problem. You could test it by openning new chrome tab, enable js console and put that handler to it, after that try to close tab and see into console.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    var x = doMyStaff();
    return x;
};

function doMyStaff(){
        console.log(new Date());
        return "Check console there are Date!"
}
```

Comment: thanks Andriy. I kind of figured it out though. There was some problem in my code. Plus, you may not return anything when using **onbeforeunload**. That was the way i wanted it to work, without alerting the user. Anyway, thanks alot. It works !